# How to combine v-for and v-model to edit a list of objects?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to edit a list of users using Vue.js. Each user has a name and an age. It seems that `v-for` is the right directive to work with lists and `v-model` is the right directive to bind the contents of an `input` to a particular element in the list.

So I tried to implement it like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    users: [{
      name: "martin",
      age: 32
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    add_user: function() {
      this.users.push({
        name: "",
        age: ""
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="exercise">
  <form id="list">
    <div></div>
    <div v-for="user in users">
      <input v-model="user.name">
      <input v-model="user.age">
      <button @click="add_user">+</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

However, once I click the button to add a new user, a new line with input fields is displayed only for a fraction of a second and then disappears, leaving the list of users containing only one element.

Please, could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `<button>` with `<form>` when you're click button it does the request automatically so its refresh or disappear because it fails to try to use `<a>` or using `<button @click.prevent="add_user" />`

```
<div id="exercise">
  <form id="list">
    <div></div>
    <div v-for="user in users">
      <input v-model="user.name">
      <input v-model="user.age">
      <a @click="add_user">+</a> //solution
      <button @click.prevent="add_user">+</button> //another solution 
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: True, but a better solution would be to add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element since semantically that is _not_ a link

Comment: So use `@click.prevent`

Answer (score 3):

The button is submitting the form, add `.prevent` to stop the action:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    users: [{
      name: "martin",
      age: 32
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    add_user () {
      this.users = [ ...this.users, {
        name: "",
        age: ""
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="exercise">
  <form id="list">
    <div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
      <input v-model="user.name" :key="`name-${index}`">
      <input v-model="user.age" :key="`age-${index}`">
    </div>
    <button @click.prevent="add_user">+</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button type="button" @click="add_user">+</button>` is more semantically correct. With `.prevent` the code says "this is a submit button (the default), but don't submit anything." With a specific type, the code doesn't pretend that it's a submit button.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set tye type of the button, since it's inside a form it fallbacks to submit button.

Also, it's good to define a :key to help vue to tell the difference between one line to another on v-for.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#exercise',
  data: {
    users: [{
      id:new Date().getTime(),
      name: "martin",
      age: 32
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    add_user: function() {
      this.users.push({
        id:new Date().getTime(),
        name: "",
        age: ""
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="exercise">
  <form id="list">
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      <input v-model="user.name">
      <input v-model="user.age">
      <button type="button" @click="add_user">+</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```